# How to import mysql-connector in IronPython (Unity)

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, ironpython, mysql-connector

EDIT: NOT SOLVED, BUT PROBLEM AVOIDED:
Instead of running a Python script which executes SQL, I have decided to just send http requests from the C# script straight to a python flask server which can then communicate with the mySQL database. If anyone knows why my original IronPython attempt doesn't work, please still let me know for any future situations! Thanks.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I am trying to connect my game to a database. I have written a Python program which can connect and send data to it, and I know that it works fine when ran by itself. However, once I run the C# script which accesses this Python script, it gives my the following error:

```
ImportException: No module named mysql.connector
Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow (System.Object value) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2[T0,TRet].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet] (T0 arg0, T1 arg1) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext ctx) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope, Microsoft.Scripting.ErrorSink errorSink) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile (System.String path, Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile (System.String path) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile(string)
StatCollector.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/StatCollector.cs:63)
```

Here is the Python code:

```
# TODO: convert all f strings to normal strings.
import mysql.connector


def connect():
    # if connection fails for some reason, an exception could be thrown,
    # which the function calling connect() must handle:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=8889,  # this port needs to be the one at the top of the
                                   # screen on phpmyadmin!!!
                                   user='root', password='root',  # unsafe!
                                   database='compsci_coursework', autocommit=True,  # database = database name you set on myphpadmin.
                                   use_pure=True, charset='utf8',
                                   collation='utf8_general_ci')  # setting you need to select when creating the db.
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return conn, cursor  # this is just where you are currently looking at in the server.


def select(sql):
    conn, cursor = connect()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def give_stats(username, p_acc_total, p_acc_ar, p_acc_pistol, p_acc_smg, p_acc_sniper, personal_best,
               bull_used_total, bull_used_ar, bull_used_pistol, bull_used_smg, bull_used_sniper, kd_average,
               total_damage_taken, games_played, total_kills):

    conn, cursor = connect()
    cursor.execute("select user_id from users where username = '" + username + "'")
    user_id = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]  # format is [(user_id,)]
    print(user_id)


    # pb:
    cursor.execute("delete from `highscores` where `user_id` = '" + user_id + "'")
    cursor.execute("insert into `highscores` (`user_id`, `personal_best`) values ('" + user_id + "', '" + personal_best + "')")

    # accuracy:
    cursor.execute("delete from `percentage_accuracy` where `user_id` = '" + user_id + "'")
    cursor.execute("insert into `percentage_accuracy` (`user_id`, `total`, `assault`, `pistol`, `smg`, `sniper`) values ('" + user_id + "', '" + p_acc_total + "', '" + p_acc_ar + "', '" + p_acc_pistol + "', '" + p_acc_smg + "', '" + p_acc_sniper + "')")

    # bullets used:
    cursor.execute("delete from `bullets_used` where `user_id` = '" + user_id + "'")
    cursor.execute("insert into `bullets_used` (`user_id`, `total`, `assault`, `pistol`, `smg`, `sniper`) values ('" + user_id + "', '" + bull_used_total + "', '" + bull_used_ar + "', '" + bull_used_pistol + "', '" + bull_used_smg + "', '" + bull_used_sniper + "')")

    # player stats:
    cursor.execute("delete from `player_stats` where `user_id` = '" + user_id + "'")
    cursor.execute("insert into `player_stats` (`user_id`, `kd_average`, `total_damage_taken`, `games_played`, `total_kills`) values ('" + user_id + "', '" + kd_average + "', '" + total_damage_taken + "', '" + games_played + "', '" + total_kills + "')")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("unity file")
    # username = input("username: ")
    # p_acc_total = float(input("p_acc_total"))
    # p_acc_ar = float(input("ar: "))
    # p_acc_pistol = float(input("pistol "))
    # p_acc_smg = float(input("smg"))
    # p_acc_sniper = float(input("sniper"))
    # personal_best = int(input("pb "))
    # bull_used_total = int(input("bull_used_total "))
    # bull_used_ar = int(input("ar"))
    # bull_used_pistol = int(input("pistol"))
    # bull_used_smg = int(input("smg"))
    # bull_used_sniper = int(input("sniper"))
    # kd_average = float(input("kd_average "))
    # total_damage_taken = int(input("total damage taken "))
    # games_played = int(input("games_played "))
    # total_kills = int(input("kills total "))

    username = 'levin'
    p_acc_total = 100.0
    p_acc_ar = 100.0
    p_acc_pistol = 100.0
    p_acc_smg = 100.0
    p_acc_sniper = 100.0
    personal_best = 1000
    bull_used_total = 10000
    bull_used_ar = 2500
    bull_used_pistol = 2500
    bull_used_smg = 2500
    bull_used_sniper = 2500
    kd_average = 1000
    total_damage_taken = 1
    games_played = 1
    total_kills = 1000

    # give_stats(username, p_acc_total, p_acc_ar, p_acc_pistol, p_acc_smg, p_acc_sniper, personal_best,
    #            bull_used_total, bull_used_ar, bull_used_pistol, bull_used_smg, bull_used_sniper, kd_average,
    #            total_damage_taken, games_played, total_kills)
```

(I've seen that stackoverflow sometimes messes up the indentation, but in the real code, it is all correct if so).

Here is the C# script which tries to run the Python program:

```
// using ideas from https://mikalikes.men/use-python-with-unity-3d-the-definitive-guide/

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using UnityEngine;

public class StatCollector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string username;

    public float percentageAccuracyTotal;
    public float percentageAccuracyAR;
    public float percentageAccuracyPistol;
    public float percentageAccuracySMG;
    public float percentageAccuracySniper;

    public int personalBest;

    public int bulletsUsedTotal;
    public int bulletsUsedAR;
    public int bulletsUsedPistol;
    public int bulletsUsedSMG;
    public int bulletsUsedSniper;

    // headshot %?

    public float killsPerGameAv;

    public int totalDamageTaken;

    public int gamesPlayed;

    public int totalKills;


    // stats to not send:
    public int hits;
    public int hitsAR;
    public int hitsPistol;
    public int hitsSMG;
    public int hitsSniper;
    private dynamic py;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

        ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

        //Path to the folder of greeter.py
        searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath);
        //Path to the Python standard library
        searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"\Plugins\Lib\");
        searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"/Scripts/mysql");
        searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"\Scripts\mysql");
        searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"/Scripts/mysql/connector");
        searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"\Scripts\mysql\connector");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);

        py = engine.ExecuteFile(Application.dataPath + @"/Scripts/send_stats.py");


        bulletsUsedTotal = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bulletsUsedTotal");
        bulletsUsedAR = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bulletsUsedAR");
        bulletsUsedPistol = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bulletsUsedPistol");
        bulletsUsedSMG = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bulletsUsedSMG");
        bulletsUsedSniper = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bulletsUsedSniper");

        percentageAccuracyTotal = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("percentageAccuracyTotal");
        percentageAccuracyAR = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("percentageAccuracyAR");
        percentageAccuracyPistol = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("percentageAccuracyPistol");
        percentageAccuracySMG = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("percentageAccuracySMG");
        percentageAccuracySniper = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("percentageAccuracySniper");

        killsPerGameAv = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("killsPerGameAv");
        totalDamageTaken = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalDamageTaken");
        gamesPlayed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("gamesPlayed");
        gamesPlayed ++;

        hits = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hits");
        hitsAR = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hitsAR");
        hitsPistol = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hitsPistol");
        hitsSMG = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hitsSMG");
        hitsSniper = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hitsSniper");

        totalKills = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalKills");

        username = PlayerPrefs.GetString("username");
    }

    public void SetStats()
    {
        percentageAccuracyTotal = bulletsUsedTotal / hits;
        percentageAccuracyAR = bulletsUsedAR / hitsAR;
        percentageAccuracyPistol = bulletsUsedPistol / hitsPistol;
        percentageAccuracySMG = bulletsUsedSMG / hitsSMG;
        percentageAccuracySniper = bulletsUsedSniper / hitsSniper;

        killsPerGameAv = totalKills / gamesPlayed;

        // sending:
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("bulletsUsedTotal", bulletsUsedTotal);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("bulletsUsedAR", bulletsUsedAR);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("bulletsUsedPistol", bulletsUsedPistol);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("bulletsUsedSMG", bulletsUsedSMG);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("bulletsUsedSniper", bulletsUsedSniper);

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("percentageAccuracyTotal", percentageAccuracyTotal);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("percentageAccuracyAR", percentageAccuracyAR);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("percentageAccuracyPistol", percentageAccuracyPistol);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("percentageAccuracySMG", percentageAccuracySMG);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("percentageAccuracySniper", percentageAccuracySniper);

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("killsPerGameAv", killsPerGameAv);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalDamageTaken", totalDamageTaken);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("gamesPlayed", gamesPlayed);

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalKills", totalKills);

        personalBest = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore");

        // not sending:
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hits", hits);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hitsAR", hitsAR);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hitsPistol", hitsPistol);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hitsSMG", hitsSMG);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hitsSniper", hitsSniper);

        SendStats();
    }

    public void SendStats()
    {
        Debug.Log(py.give_stats(username, percentageAccuracyTotal.ToString(), percentageAccuracyAR.ToString(), percentageAccuracyPistol.ToString(), percentageAccuracySMG.ToString(), percentageAccuracySniper.ToString(), personalBest.ToString(), bulletsUsedTotal.ToString(), bulletsUsedAR.ToString(), bulletsUsedPistol.ToString(), bulletsUsedSMG.ToString(), bulletsUsedSniper.ToString(), killsPerGameAv.ToString(),totalDamageTaken.ToString(), gamesPlayed.ToString(), totalKills.ToString()));
    }
}
```

as you can see I have tried to ask it to set many different search paths for the same things, as I'm not sure how the \ or / effects it, and am not sure if I should use the mysql directory or the connector directory within that one.

What I have done to try to fix the problem:

1. copied and pasted the `mysql` directory from `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages` into the Unity folder: `Assets/Plugins/Lib`
2. copied the `connector` directory into the same `Lib` folder in the Unity project
3. researched for several hours about the problem.

None of these have even changed the error.

Please could someone tell me how to install the module `mysql-connector` in IronPython being used in Unity? Thanks

Edit:

I have changed the python code to now say

```
from mysql import connector as connector
```

instead of the original

```
import mysql.connector
```

and I have the following error instead:

```
ImportException: No module named io
Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow (System.Object value) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2[T0,TRet].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet] (T0 arg0) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule (System.String fileName, IronPython.Runtime.ModuleContext moduleContext, Microsoft.Scripting.ScriptCode scriptCode, IronPython.Runtime.ModuleOptions options) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule (System.String fileName, System.String moduleName, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit sourceCode, IronPython.Runtime.ModuleOptions options, Microsoft.Scripting.ScriptCode& scriptCode) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule (System.String fileName, System.String moduleName, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit sourceCode, IronPython.Runtime.ModuleOptions options) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit sourceCode, System.String name, System.String path) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.String path) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.String fullName, System.String str) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.String fullName, IronPython.Runtime.List path, System.Func`5[T1,T2,T3,T4,TResult] defaultLoader) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.String fullName, IronPython.Runtime.List path) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.Object globals, System.String modName, System.Boolean bottom, System.Int32 level) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__ (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.Object globals, System.Object locals, System.Object fromlist, System.Int32 level) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run8[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRet] (T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String fullName, IronPython.Runtime.PythonTuple from, System.Int32 level) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportWithNames (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String fullName, System.String[] names, System.Int32 level) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`5[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet] (T0 arg0) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule (System.String fileName, IronPython.Runtime.ModuleContext moduleContext, Microsoft.Scripting.ScriptCode scriptCode, IronPython.Runtime.ModuleOptions options) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule (System.String fileName, System.String moduleName, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit sourceCode, IronPython.Runtime.ModuleOptions options, Microsoft.Scripting.ScriptCode& scriptCode) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule (System.String fileName, System.String moduleName, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit sourceCode, IronPython.Runtime.ModuleOptions options) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit sourceCode, System.String name, System.String path) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.String path) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadPackageFromSource (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.String path) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.String fullName, System.String str) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.String fullName, IronPython.Runtime.List path, System.Func`5[T1,T2,T3,T4,TResult] defaultLoader) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.String name, System.String fullName, IronPython.Runtime.List path) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportNestedModule (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, IronPython.Runtime.PythonModule module, System.String[] parts, System.Int32 current, IronPython.Runtime.List path) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFrom (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.Object from, System.String name) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportFrom (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext context, System.Object module, System.String name) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4[T0,T1,T2,TRet].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet] (T0 arg0, T1 arg1) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext ctx) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope, Microsoft.Scripting.ErrorSink errorSink) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile (System.String path, Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile (System.String path) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile(string)
StatCollector.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/StatCollector.cs:65)
```

I have also added the following two lines of C# code before running `engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths)`:

```
searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"\Scripts\");
searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"/Scripts/");
```

I did this because currently the mysql directory is in `/Scripts/`.

I hope this helps.